# Update to FAQ about iTunes Connect being on-topic

Tags: support, faq, site-scope

I have [updated the main site's FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) to include wording that allows iTunes Connect to be on-topic.

Here is a short rationalization and summary of where the line is between what would be considered a developer question (generally off topic) and a user question (generally on topic)

---

We have changed the scope in April, 2013 to include limited questions relating to iTunes Connect. Parts of the [Apple Developer Programs](https://developer.apple.com) or other non-NDA encumbered [iTunes Connect](http://www.apple.com/itunes/sellcontent/) questions **are now allowed** assuming they follow the normal rules for a good question. *Our rule of thumb covering NDA is if you can directly link the question or answer to a **public Apple web page** without needing to sign an NDA, it's on topic here.* We do not intend to solicit any input or content that would put the asker or answerer in jeopardy of violating an NDA agreement that they may or may not have with Apple.

---

Let me know in comments or an answer if you see any unintended consequences. As always, ask a new question on Meta if you have questions about what specific items should or should not be on the main site or just want to ask how or why this change has happened.